# Suppress CAST() warnings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL in strict mode (`SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'`) to convert all warnings to errors. However, I have a query that is *expected* to create warnings because it tries to convert a `VARCHAR` field that might be empty or contain letters to an integer.

Example:

```
mysql> select CAST("123b" AS SIGNED);
+------------------------+
| CAST("123b" AS SIGNED) |
+------------------------+
|                    123 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '123b' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a way to suppress the warning caused by the `CAST()` *without disabling strict mode*? Or alternatively, can the strict mode be disabled for a **single query or function** (something like the `@` operator in PHP) **without** calling `SET` twice to temporarily switch off the strict mode?

*Background: I have a table with street numbers. Most of them are numeric but some contain letters at the end. To implement a simplistic "natural sort" I'd like to use `ORDER BY CAST (StreetNr AS SIGNED), StreetNr` and the value returned by CAST() would be just fine for 1st level sorting.*

Comment: What issues do you experience having that warnings?

Comment: As said, I'm using strict mode in MySQL that turns all warnings into errors. I need that to make sure that MySQL checks the validity of (other) data fields. By CAST()ing in the ORDER BY clause I get a number of (technically correct) warnings that make my query fail completely. I need to tell MySQL that the CAST() should not produce any warnings/errors or that those warnings don't get converted to errors because I *expect* them. Without strict mode the query would succeed, but I would like to avoid that nasty workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the problem is that you are trying to insert data from one table into another using a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

And the inserts are failing because of the `CAST()` problem you described in your question.

Is that accurate?

If so, the easiest way around this is to use `INSERT IGNORE`. That syntax is useful for ignoring duplicate key errors, but it can also be used to ignore the `CAST()` errors that are affecting you.

Your updated query would look something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO target_table
SELECT ...
FROM source_table
WHERE ...
ORDER BY CAST (StreetNr AS SIGNED), StreetNr
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with ordering and used regexp first:

```
ORDER BY CAST(CONCAT('0', REGEXP_REPLACE(StreetNr, '[^0-9]', '')) AS INTEGER)
```

The concat-0 is to handle an empty string.
(My server is MariaDB, but it should be the same as MySQL.)